# TYPO3 FileReference does not save the tablename on the DB. Uploading file from frontend on TYPO3

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-10.x, filereference

In my custom extension on TYPO3 10.4 I'm trying to upload a file (image) from the frontend. The file gets uploaded just fine, the rows on the DB seemed to be inserted just fine but there is some data missing.

This is my form:

```xml
    <f:form method="post" action="create" name="blackboard"
                              object="{blackboard}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <f:form.textfield placeholder="Titel*" required="true" property="title"></f:form.textfield>
         <f:form.upload property="image" name="image" />
         <f:form.submit class="btn btn-primary" value="{f:translate(key: 'submit', default: 'Absenden')}"></f:form.submit>
    </f:form>
```

The model:

```php
     /**
     * image
     * 
     * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference
     * @TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Annotation\ORM\Cascade("remove")
     */
    protected $image = null;
     /**
     * Returns the image
     * 
     * @return \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the image
     * 
     * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image
     * @return void
     */
    public function setImage(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FileReference $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
    }
```

The controller:

```php
     /**
     * action create 
     * @param Blackboard
     */
    public function createAction(Blackboard $blackboard)
    {
        $blackboard->setPid($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['EXTENSIONS']['hebo_blackboards']['BlackboardsStoragePId']);
        $blackboard->setUser($GLOBALS['TSFE']->fe_user->user['uid']);
        $this->blackboardRepository->add($blackboard);
    }
```

Surprisingly, just that easy, this seems to work just fine. I get the image uploaded on the server, the correct UID of that sys_file_reference on my custom table, the sys_file_reference gets the correct UID of that sys_file... but as you can see in the pic that follows there are a few data missing, "tablename" and "table_local" and as soon as I add that data manually the relationships work (the first rows, where this data is not missing is from rows created from the backend, working fine)

[image]

My question is, why? What do I do to fix that?

Comment: your promised pic is still missing :)

Comment: haha omg, sorry and thanks

Comment: it looks like you are on your own (cite from manual: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Fal/UsingFal/ExamplesFileFolder.html#in-the-frontend-context). if you have managed to store the file you might update the reference after you created you own record, inserting the table and fieldnames. Reading through the example I think you might miss to extend the filereference. But as I have not needed this I have no experience and someone with more experience can give you a full solution.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I think I will just update that values manually and see if I can go with that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that extbase doesn't know those values, therefore you need to state those in the TCA. Given this example

```php
'extra_files' => [
    'label' => 'A file',
    'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig(
        'extra_files',
        [
            'foreign_match_fields' => [
                'tablenames' => 'tx_yourtable_domain_model_fo',
                'table_local' => 'sys_file'
            ]
        ],
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext']
    ),
],
```

The `foreign_match_fields` part is the relevant one which is not needed if you don't handle file uploads in the Frontend.